# After Payment, in Magento's back-end total paid = 0 and total due >0

Tags: php, magento, payment

```
            $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
            $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $order_status = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
            if($configured_order_status == 'pending') {
               $order_status = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT;
            }
            $order->setState($order_status, true, $comment);

            $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            $order->setEmailSent(true);

            $order->save();
```

This is a part of the code from PaymentController.php. In the admin page after payment is done, total due > 0 while total paid = 0. Please tell me what function am I missing. I couldn't find satisfactory answer in similar type of questions, so re-asking it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to goto sales->order->select an order. Then click on invoice button and then on submit invoice. This will do... :)